# Skip "add state" and go directly to "edit state"

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-gridcontrol

I'm using DevExpress. I have a GridView / GridControl which's data I read and process when certain columns are edited. I use the GridControl's embedded navigator, and I noticed that when I add a new row (with the +) the new row is in a special mode where three things stand out: Pressing esc removes the entire row, the icon the left is a cursor instead of the "editing sheet" icon and the row cannot be manually selected (which effectively disables multi-selections that include that new row). However, I want none of these things. Is it possible to skip this state of being added when inserting new rows, so that it is immediately in the editing state (usual icon, esc only cancels current cell, row can be selected)?

Comment: Let alone that your question has [severe quality issues](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (IMO), I cannot understand that anyone asks DevExpress questions here on SO instead of [directly in the _awesome_ support forum at DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create).

Comment: DevExpress support has been no help so far.